# Set Default Build Action for image files or files in general

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio, buildaction

I'm using Xamarin Studio.  Is it possible to set the default build action for custom files or image files?

I'm developing an app that uses A LOT of PNG images.  BundleResource is set by default for every image I import into the project.  I noticed that my memory usage decreases by about ~25mb (from 220 to about 193mb) when I build my images using **Content** as opposed to the default **BundleResource**.

"MonoDevelop should automatically choose the BundleResource build action, but you can check or set this manually using in each file’s properties."

-http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/monodevelop_features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not appear that a default build action can be set.  However, when adding the files to the project the Add files dialog provides the option to override the build action that the files will be imported to use.

In this way you can select a bunch of the PNG images and import them with Content from the get go.

http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2011/03/monodevelop_tips_build_actions

Comment: Yeah that does help, but I typically add all my files into my project via Add Existing Folder or just simply by dragging and dropping folders.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend against using the `Content` build action. The `BundleResource` build action was added later and is more powerful, however the only difference between them is the mapping from the file's location in your project to the file's location in the app bundle. The `Content` build action has only been kept for backwards compatibility.

If you're seeing different memory use there must be some other reason for it. Have you tried comparing the two versions of your app bundle?

Content files are copied into the app bundle with a relative path matching their relative path within your project. BundleResource files are treated the same, *except* that if their are in the project's Resource directory, this prefix is stripped off. The idea is that you can copy things into the root of the app bundle, as required by Apple APIs, without cluttering up the root of your project.

So, for example, with `BundleResource` build action, the file `Resources\Foo\Bar.png` in yur project would be copied to `Foo\Bar.png` in the app bundle. Whereas with the `Content` build action it would be copied to `Resources\Foo\Bar.png` (though you're not allowed to have a directory called "Resources" inside your app bundle since it's an Apple reserved name, so you'd get an error).

`BundleResource` also supports a `IPhoneResourcePrefix` project property you can only set by manually editing the csproj file that allow you to define more directories to be treated this way, for example you could have an Images directory. This gives you more control over organizing your resources. You can also use the `LogicalName` item metadata on any `BundleResource` item to completely override its bundle-relative location.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information!  Looks like I'll end up using BundleResource then.  I am still seeing the different memory usage between the two Build Actions.  That actually scares me making me think I"m doing something awful!  I'm doing A LOT of UIImage.FromFiles() and CIFilters.  Everything seems to be working though so I'm not going to worry.  If I come up with any more information on the subject I'll let you know.